# Can anyone help me on a sql code?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi every one I wrote a SQL code but I want to run it on phpMYadmin it get error:

The SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'urls'(
'url' text NOT NULL,
'code' text NOT NUll,
'ip' text NOT NULL,
'visited' int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The phpMYadmin problem :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''urls'( 'url' text NOT NULL, 'code' text NOT NUll, 'ip' text NOT NULL, 'visi' at line 1
```

Comment: try to remove single quote from table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `''` to `` [back ticks around your url- table name]

Tested at phpmyadmin-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `url`(
`url` text NOT NULL,
`code` text NOT NUll,
`ip` text NOT NULL,
`visited` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT charset = utf8;
```

Comment: Even better: avoid quoted identifiers (btw: MySQL would also support the ANSI standard using a double quote `"`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thx for the comment..but i think if a user uses reserved keyword in naming table then he/she has to use this back ticks....correct me at any point if I am wrong..happy to be clear with the fundamentals

Comment: No. He/she should not use reserved words at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `urls` (
`url` text NOT NULL,
`code` text NOT NULL,
`ip` text NOT NULL,
`visited` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```